# Oracle 11: Joining two selects

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table 'useroption', which lists users with their selected options.

Options can have items. The table 'option' holds the items for each option.

I want to know which users have item 1234 active:

```
SELECT uo.userid FROM useroption uo 
     WHERE option IN (SELECT option FROM items WHERE item = 1234)
AND uo.start_date <= SYSDATE AND (uo.end_date > SYSDATE)
AND uo.bill_start_date <= SYSDATE AND (uo.bill_end_date > SYSDATE)
```

This gives me a list of users who have options which hold item 1234 and have an active date.

So far so good.

Now I need to extend this with a second item:

I want to know which users have item 1234 AND item 3456 active. In other words, which users have an active option for item 1234 and an active option for item 3456.

Current solution:

```
SELECT a.userid FROM (
    SELECT uo.userid FROM useroption uo WHERE option IN (SELECT option FROM items WHERE item = 1234)
        AND uo.start_date <= SYSDATE AND (uo.end_date > SYSDATE)
        AND uo.bill_start_date <= SYSDATE AND (uo.bill_end_date > SYSDATE)
) b JOIN (
    SELECT uo.userid FROM useroption uo WHERE option IN (SELECT option FROM items WHERE item = 3456)
        AND uo.start_date <= SYSDATE AND (uo.end_date > SYSDATE)
        AND uo.bill_start_date <= SYSDATE AND (uo.bill_end_date > SYSDATE)
) b ON a.userid = b.userid
```

Do you perhaps know if there is a more elegant way to solve this than to just copy paste join the same query again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT uo.userid
FROM useroption uo JOIN
     items i
     ON uo.option = i.option
WHERE i.item IN (1234, 3456) AND
      uo.start_date <= SYSDATE AND 
      uo.end_date > SYSDATE AND
      uo.bill_start_date <= SYSDATE AND 
      uo.bill_end_date > SYSDATE
GROUP BY uo.userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.item) = 2;  -- has both items
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below using conditional aggregation

```
    SELECT uo.userid FROM useroption uo WHERE option IN (SELECT option FROM items WHERE item in( 1234,3456))
        AND uo.start_date <= SYSDATE AND (uo.end_date > SYSDATE)
        AND uo.bill_start_date <= SYSDATE AND (uo.bill_end_date > SYSDATE) 
       group by uo.userid   
       having count(distinct option)=2
```